# Woodcarving where do i start?

Tags: carving

I want to take up the hobby of wood carving/whittling . I watched a few videos but theres none that start from very basic instructions. I would like to make things from branches of different sizes frim the woods . I can identify pine n ithers so know which is hard or soft wood .

What i am asking is for helpful tips on carving that can help me build my skills and confidence to do bigger and bigger projects . Let it be noted i want to do this all with basic handtools.

Comment: I suspect this Question is just too broad and might be closed, but like with all things you should probably start small and work up, and start with a basic toolkit (maybe just one knife) and then buy more stuff over time as you identify the need and as budget allows. Doing it in a pure whittling mode you really only need a couple/three knives which you'll use for pretty much everything. [contd]

Comment: In case you don't know, you do also need sharpening gear right from the start as carving tools need to be as sharp as possible. If you use the internal search here to look for whittling you'll get loads of related information from previous Questions.

Comment: Did you google "how to start woodcarving"? I just did and literally every result on the first page looks like a good resource. Voted to close as this is too broad and the asker hasn't done their own research seemingly.

Comment: Pick a project you're excited about that seems reasonable for you to complete. Figure out what you need (tools, techniques, etc.) to do it. That's pretty much the only way. You could take a class, but even then, at the end of the class, you're looking at picking a project and getting started.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a stupidly obvious answer, but get a good, solid pocket knife, and just start carving wood with it. Whittling is one of the lowest barrier-to-entry hobbies there is. Making something (anything) will teach you enough to pick out your next project, and you can expand your tools from there to match your purpose.

If you must buy a tool, Narex makes a [good basic carving knife](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B010W7ND4U). Another option is one by [Pfeil](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BVRSOVW). Flexcut's [palm tool set](https://www.japanwoodworker.com/products/set-of-9-palm-tools?via=58923197617070231a00002d%2C58923197617070231a000032) is good for the next step.

Since you're a beginner, you should also buy a kevlar or spectra cut glove for your non-cutting hand, and maybe a thumb and finger guard for your cutting hand. You may find that you don't need these after some experience but they will save you a lot of bandaids when you're first starting out.